Beautiful and colorful: Reveal the last one
Find 22 of the same kind (letters are orthogonal connected, not diagonal).
After that, reveal the 23th one.

CSV:
,,,,,,,,,U,S,I,P,O,S,A,S,I,G,G
,,,,,,,,,H,E,L,I,R,T,H,U,E,U,E
,,,24,20,18,,,,D,G,R,U,A,M,S,U,T,D,H
,,,16,15,18,,,,E,U,R,T,U,L,F,I,U,E,G
,,,P,22,12,,,,U,U,D,P,E,R,H,S,D,D,I
,,,P,18,N,,,,H,L,I,U,U,I,O,I,U,S,T
,,,14,O,16,,,,T,Y,S,I,N,E,N,S,E,D,U
,,,,,,,,,O,E,D,E,T,B,L,I,S,E,U
,,,,,,,,,M,I,E,U,I,I,L,K,A,S,I
I,U,T,D,S,T,T,E,F,R,A,F,I,E,M,I,X,H,H,D
F,A,B,E,D,T,I,U,U,H,E,T,E,L,E,S,T,P,S,I
A,L,O,R,S,S,H,U,G,L,E,T,M,H,T,A,E,A,P,I
R,L,S,B,O,M,M,F,G,S,R,N,G,C,I,D,H,E,P,L
F,A,L,O,T,U,E,R,K,K,L,I,S,S,T,S,U,R,A,L
S,S,E,Y,L,H,T,I,E,O,L,A,H,S,G,I,P,T,G,O
G,A,T,U,F,R,P,R,B,E,N,P,E,T,O,R,A,U,T,N
I,H,D,H,E,E,E,L,E,U,T,P,M,U,I,D,E,I,L,L
U,E,T,G,I,T,I,S,L,P,A,E,R,L,J,N,R,P,N,A
D,G,T,B,U,T,U,D,E,K,P,G,I,V,L,I,H,O,G,T
D,T,U,E,T,H,E,G,I,S,A,L,L,O,N,A,E,U,G,S


This wordsearch puzzle hides...

 ...22 words meaning 'butterfly' (a creature renowned for being beautiful and colourful, as per the title) in various languages. They can be found in the grid as follows:



(The lines in red just show that unfortunately for the Estonian contribution LIBLIKAS there are two ways to resolve the final 'S', and I wasn't sure which was intended, if that was even important...)

 The list of words (and languages) is (in the order I found them):

 BUTTERFLY (English)
 PAPILLON (French)
MOTH (English)
 MARIPOSA (Spanish)
 BORBOLETA (Portuguese)
 VLINDER (Dutch)
 PERHONEN (Finnish)
 FLUTUR (Albanian)
 KELEBEK (Turkish)
 SOMMERFUGL (Danish/Norwegian)
 FARFALLA (Italian)
 LEPTIR (Croatian)
 SCHMETTERLING (German)
 SKOENLAPPER (Afrikaans)
 PAPALLONA (Catalan)
 FARFETT (Maltese)
 METULJ (Slovenian)
 PARU-PARO (Tagalog)
 LIBLIKAS (Estonian)
 TXIMELETA (Basque)
 PILLANGO (Hungarian)
 DRUGELIS (Lithuanian)
 MOTYL (Polish, among others)

 My break-in to this was spotting the word 'butterfly' among all my many words I'd been toying with in this wordsearch, and then the word 'papillon' which I knew to be the French equivalent. When I then found 'moth' (incorrectly, it would turn out, since actually the word I sought here was the Polish word 'motyl' that happened to share many of its letters), I searched the internet for other foreign translations of the word 'butterfly' and started to spot the most obvious ones (from my European perspective anyway - Spanish, Portuguese, Dutch, and so on). Eventually I stumbled upon this helpful site which helped me find the rest through Ctrl+F searching potential substrings I was finding in the grid.

If instead of using lines we indicate these words by shading the boxes, we see the following:

 

 If you tilt your head to the left to look at it along its diagonal axis (and squint a bit) you could argue that this looks a bit like a butterfly in shape, with two wings and two antenna bordering the empty top-left section - so here is our 23rd!

But... does it really resemble a butterfly that closely? Perhaps there's something further we need to do in this puzzle to make this image a bit sharper...

Up to this point I have not used the smaller grid in the top-left corner at all:
24-20-18 / 16-15-18 / P-22-12 / P-18-N / 14-O-16.
Look at the numbers within it: 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, and 24. And let's also look at...

 ...the letters that have not been used in this puzzle grid. The same letters seem to appear among the leftovers over and over again many times, suggesting that these unused letters have not just been selected at random. 'U', for example, appears 24 times, 'I' 22 times, and 'S' 20 times... Hey, wait! These frequencies correspond to the numbers used in that smaller grid!

 So let's count up all the leftover letters. We have: 12 G's, 14 D's, 15 H's, 16 T's, 18 E's, 20 S's, 22 I's, and 24 U's.

 If we substitute these for the numbers in the smaller grid we read a message:

 USE / THE / PIG / PEN / DOT

 This suggests we should make use of the Pigpen cipher somehow - but how exactly? After some dead-end thinking (in which I persuaded myself that this woman was the 23rd in question - see the edit history for the full story), @Deusovi pointed out in comments what I had missed...

 Let's ask: What happens if we just focus on the 13 letters of the alphabet which utilise a dot in their Pigpen cipher encoding? That would be the letters J-R and W-Z...



 If we highlight just those letters - none of which appear among the unused letters, note (explaining why the in-range N, O and P are given rather than concealed by their frequencies in the smaller grid) we see the following image:



 Now that's the 23rd we're looking for - a crisp depiction of the outline of a butterfly! (Thanks @Deusovi for the push over the finish line there...)


Great progress there, @Stiv! However, the final answer isn't correct. There is a better fitting solution ;)

Perhaps you should do this?

@Deusovi Ah, I see what you mean! (Although I think one of your columns has somehow moved a few to the right...) Thanks :)

Ah, it has - that's what I get for reusing this sheet and not noticing I had moved some things around... anyway, nice job on the solve for the rest! I stared at it a while and couldn't find anything.

@Stiv, I used a different source for Albania, but I am not native, so I am not sure which is right. Google translate  recognised flutur. And sorry for the last S of the Estonian one. Should have double checked it.. :(

@Lezzup Ah, I see. Well, I am also not an Albanian native speaker (!) so I will amend my answer and visuals when I'm next on a laptop in order to be fair to your puzzle :) The 'S' is unfortunate but hey it happens. That stray H had me going for a while! Was glad when I finally worked out what I'd done there...
